# Connect to MySQL using Windows Authentication

Tags: mysql, windows

Is it possible to have Wordpress/PHP connect to my MySQL database using [Windows Authentication](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/windows-authentication-plugin.html) on IIS? I can connect just fine using the normal MySQL command line utilities. I get the following error instead:

```
Warning: mysqli_real_connect(): The server requested authentication method unknown to the client [authentication_windows_client] in c:\wordpress\wp-includes\wp-db.php on line 1386

Warning: mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2054): The server requested authentication method unknown to the client in c:\wordpress\wp-includes\wp-db.php on line 1386

Deprecated: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in c:\wordpress\wp-includes\wp-db.php on line 1416

Warning: mysql_connect(): The server requested authentication method unknown to the client [authentication_windows_client] in c:\wordpress\wp-includes\wp-db.php on line 1416

Warning: mysql_connect(): The server requested authentication method unknown to the client in c:\wordpress\wp-includes\wp-db.php on line 1416
```

Comment: Are you modifying WordPress Core? If so this is extremely bad. There are far better ways to change the behavior of WPDB than editing the core files directly

Comment: @TomJNowell I haven't done that at all. I'm using an official auth plugin for MySQL as I linked above.

Comment: Very late I know, but I'd guess you just have to make sure that your PHP is using the enterprise version of the mysql client libraries rather than the one it was supplied with. This may mean rebuilding the php_mysqli extension. You might also need to prevent WordPress trying to supply a password, albeit an empty one, which you can probably do by a drop-in db.php to modify the wpdb class.

Answer (score -1):

This is just bad security method.

Because the only way you can connect to the mysql database is via that pc you use.

Where is if you username/pwd, you can move the site to another server, etc.

So Windows Authentication is a bad idea,  too easy to overcome, and honestly just not that secure.

Where as a username and strong password, that changes every so often, that's much better security.

But it's like this, if your insistent on driving your car over a cliff, we won't get in your way, but you won't like the results of your choices.

Comment: Why is this bad? If someone compromises my webserver, they can already access my database.

Comment: If someone compromises your database that doesn't mean they've compromised your entire server, but if the details are the same...

Comment: That's not how it works. You use a service account that runs the website makes it perfectly secure. Compromising the website does not give someone access to the entire server. That's the point of service accounts.